# Tortoise-Hare Rank Comparison?

Tags: ordinal-data, ranking

Some time ago I ran across a great reference which I have since lost. I'm hoping that either someone will know the source I'm talking about or be able to point me to the same test.

Basically the argument is that you want to reproduce the classic tortoise and hare race to determine if the result was a fluke or not. You run 10 of each animal and record their finishing place. This results in the set below.

R1={H, H, T, H, H, H, T, T, H, T, T, T, H, H, T, H, T, H, T, T}

The statistical test then looks at how many Hares are beat by each Tortoise. The result determines which set T or H is higher ranked OR if the result is somewhere in the noise of permutation.

In other words if {H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T} would definitely say that Hares win and {T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H,H} definitely says Tortoises win, then the result R1 must be somewhere in the spectrum between the two. There are 2^20 permutations and R1 has a higher T win rate than some percentage of them x. The question is then if X is above a specific threshold to be significant. If R1 has a 1 in 100 chance of occuring it is not so important. If it has a 1 in 10,000 chance of occuring, then it may be statistically significant.

Does anyone know what the test is or how to perform the analysis?

-----------------------EDIT----------------------------------------

Not to get too far away from the Tortoise Hare concept, but this test would also work for testing two diets meant to improve test scores. If you create two groups, using two different diets, score the tests and determine which diet produced better results. I suppose it could be done using three groups as well. The important issue is that one group has a rank compared to other groups and then that ranking is attained only with a specific probability. That probability relates to statistical significance.

Comment: I like the Wilson binomial confidence interval indicator.  Jeffrey's also does it.  Tortoise vs hare also works for unfair coin.  Are you looking at "if I get a series of wins that are "N" long, does it mean equal odds aren't in the 95% CI?"

Comment: @EngrStudent Not quite. Remember that this is one race conducted with 20 animals and you get only one result. That is entirely different from a coin toss where you perform the same operation 20 times. Also, the rank is important here. If first place is a Hare, he has beaten all ten Tortoises. In a coin toss it really doesn't matter which order you get.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test

Comment: @whuber Yep, that is it. Wikipedia will do very well. I would like to give you the credit for finding it. Can  you phrase it as an answer?